# A way to make multiple transactions in NEAR in a smart contract look bundled or more obscure from the outside?

Tags: rust, smartcontracts, nearprotocol

Let's say I have a method in a Rust smart, and in it multiple transactions are made:

```
pub fn test1(&self, addr1: AddressId, addr2: AddressId, addr3: AddressId, addr4: AddressId) {
    
    let p1 = Promise::new(addr1).transfer(11);
    let p2 = Promise::new(addr2).transfer(366);
    let p3 = Promise::new(addr3).transfer(99);
    let p4 = Promise::new(addr4).transfer(65456);
}
```

As I understand, all 4 will appear on blockchain/explorer **as are**, right? 4 tx-s and 4 receivers.

If so, is there any way to still send coins all 4 addresses, but somehow obfuscate the fact, or make it less clear in anyway? On blockchain and consequently on an explorer, that is.

Or make it look like a bundled transaction, somehow, which sends coins somewhere, but  it's not possible to find out whom to and how many recepients there're?

I don't mean creating something like Tornado.cash, but rather a simple, standard solution which NEAR may be capable of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently NEAR does not support such mechanism out of the box.